# Number of ways to choose 4 different beers of each type from a set of n

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> In order to celebrate that the midterm went well, you go to your neighborhood
>   pub. This pub has 16 different beers on tap:
>
> - There are 7 beers of the pilsner type.
> - There are 5 beers of the India pale ale type.
> - There are 4 beers of the German wheatbeer type.
>
> You order 4 different beers with at least one beer of each type. What is the number of ways
>   in which you can do this? (The order in which you order the beers does not matter.)
>
> (a) ${16}\choose{4}$
>   **(b) ${{7}\choose{2}} \cdot 5 \cdot 4 + 7 \cdot {{5}\choose{2}} \cdot 4 + 7 \cdot 5 \cdot {{4}\choose{2}}$**
>   (c) ${{16}\choose{4}} - {{7}\choose{3}} - {{5}\choose{3}} - {{4}\choose{3}} $
>   (d) None of the above

The answer is **(b)**.

My guess was **(d)** because:

- There must be at least one beer of each type. This is the same as calculating the number of beers that aren't of each type (it's going to be 4 of one type):

  ${{16}\choose{4}} - {{7}\choose{4}} - {{5}\choose{4}} - {{4}\choose{4}} $

I realized though, that you could also choose from only 2 types of beer and that would also satisfy what I have said above, so I am wrong.

Why is **(b)** correct?

Comment: The possible patterns are $(2,1,1), (1,2,1), (1,1,2)$ with, I hope, obvious notation.  Let's count $(2,1,1)$ as an example.  There are then $\binom 72$ ways to pick the two pilsners, $\binom 51=5$ ways to pick your one ale, and $\binom 41=4$ ways to pick your wheatbeer.  So...$\binom 72\times 5\times 4$ ways to populate this pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could choose $2$ Pilsners, $1$ Indian Ale and $1$ German beer (PPIG), thats $\binom{7}{2} \binom{5}{1} \binom{4}{1}$.

Similarly you could choose PIIG thats $\binom{7}{1} \binom{5}{2} \binom{4}{1}$.

Or PIGG thats $\binom{7}{1} \binom{5}{1} \binom{4}{2}$.

So the answer is $\color{red}{(b)}$.